# Using sonarqube with apache derby

Tags: sonarqube, derby

I am planning to use sonarqube. I have successfully installed sonarqube. AT the moment i am using the embedded h2 database which we shall only use for evaluation purpose. I went through the documentations and found out that sonarqube support MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle and PostgreSql. I was wondering if it possible to setup sonarqube with Apache Derby? If yes then can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Derby used to be Sonar's default embedded database and was recently replaced by H2.

Is there are reason to favour Derby? I'm personally a big big fan of H2. In practice, you are best advised to use something like MySQL for non-trivial Sonar installations.

Comment: No there is no special reason to use apache derby.Just wanted to play around with sonar and apache derby.

Answer (score 0):

As you perfectly read on the [requirements page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements), Derby is not supported.